# How to export the value from the promise

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I am fairly new to node and mongoose and I am having some issues with `module.exports`. While trying to make my code a bit more clean I have been trying to use modules to take the mongoDB queries since they take too much space and it does not that easy to read, but I got an error.

Here I am merging 2 collections to get a result but the console on index.js tells me undefined. When I do a console.log on operations.js and then execute on index, the console from inside return the array but not the one outside.

After a bit of reading I see that is because the value i want is inside of the promise, but how can I get it back then?

operations.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const CheckOutOrder = require('../models/CheckOutOrder')

function ordersQuery(){
    console.log('lol')
    CheckOutOrder.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
                'is_open':1
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields:{
                'itemToMatch':{
                    $toObjectId:'$idItem'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup:{
            from: 'e_menu_items',
            localField: 'itemToMatch',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'itemsReceipt'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind:'$itemsReceipt'
        }
    ]).then(info => {
       console.log(info) 
       return info
    }).catch(e => {
       console.log('e') 
       return e
    })
}

module.exports.totOrders = ordersQuery
```

index.js

```
const mongoQueries = require('../mongo/operations')

if(ActionDOM=='test'){
        let orders = []
        orders = mongoQueries.totOrders()
        console.log('------------------------------------------------------')
        console.log(orders)
    }
```

console

```
lol
------------------------------------------------------
undefined
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61da4036bc966b2a284e8075"),
    idReceipt: 4,
    idUser: '61d1606420f281d51d52e2e1',
    idItem: '61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed',
    is_open: 1,
    date_added: 2022-01-09T01:53:58.017Z,
    __v: 0,
    itemToMatch: new ObjectId("61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed"),
    itemsReceipt: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed"),
      menuItem: 'Molletes',
      description: 'Frijoles, queso y salsa',
      price: 18,
      id_cat: 1,
      is_active: 1,
      date_added: 2022-01-07T08:26:08.990Z,
      date_modified: 2022-01-07T08:26:08.990Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61da4036bc966b2a284e8079"),
    idReceipt: 4,
    idUser: '61d1606420f281d51d52e2e1',
    idItem: '61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed',
    is_open: 1,
    date_added: 2022-01-09T01:53:58.128Z,
    __v: 0,
    itemToMatch: new ObjectId("61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed"),
    itemsReceipt: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61d7f9205bda9c3be60b14ed"),
      menuItem: 'Molletes',
      description: 'Frijoles, queso y salsa',
      price: 18,
      id_cat: 1,
      is_active: 1,
      date_added: 2022-01-07T08:26:08.990Z,
      date_modified: 2022-01-07T08:26:08.990Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `ordersQuery` doesn't `return` anything. Put a `return` keyword in front of that promise chain.

Comment: You don't want to `return e`, you want to re-`throw` it after logging it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `async/await` to make the code more "linear":

```
async function ordersQuery() {
  console.log('lol');

  try {
    const info = await CheckOutOrder.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          is_open: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          itemToMatch: {
            $toObjectId: '$idItem',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'e_menu_items',
          localField: 'itemToMatch',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'itemsReceipt',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$itemsReceipt',
      },
    ]);

    console.log(info);

    return info;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

    return e;
  }
}
```

and then call it with `await` too (the calling function must be declared `async`):

```
async function someFunc(/*....*/) {
  // ...
  
  if (ActionDOM == 'test') {
    let orders = [];
    orders = await mongoQueries.totOrders();
    console.log('------------------------------------------------------');
    console.log(orders);
  }

  // ...
}
```